# JScrollPane causing HTML5 Audio to auto-pause

Tags: jquery, html, jscrollpane, html5-audio, jquery-jscrollpane

Facing a weird issue when using JScrollPane (http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/index.html#support) and HTML5 Audio tags. In a nutshell:

I have a div which I am using Jscrollpane on. The div contains html5 audio. I play the html5 audio. Then I call destroy on the Jscrollpane. Upon calling destroy, the html5 audio stops playing. Similarly, if I am playing html5 audio and I initialize Jscrollpane on the parent div, the html5 audio stops playing.

What can explain this behavior? I know it has to do with html5 audio specifically because when I use flash to play the audio instead of html5, this problem does not occur.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guess it's because the audio node is a child of the parent DOM node that jScrollPane is modifying. So the audio node that is playing is destroyed and a brand new one is inserted into the DOM.

Comment: Yea that is correct. What is weird is that even if I force flash on all browsers, Chrome still stops playing the audio. Firefox and Safari work.